# Seperate DTO for post and put request & nested json as post model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have two questions about RESTful api.
**1.** Can we have separate DTO for GET, POST and PUT request? Is it good practice 
or can I make one abstract class with common properties and then inherit from it?
**2.** Is sending nested json in POST request a good practice?

As did in following article: 
https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part6/

Comment: Could you add more content/code/model for your question to explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, and more to the point, you *should*. A DTO is a representation of a particular group of data in a particular scenario. That data can and will be different between different request types. Any time there's different data being transferred, there should be a different DTO to represent it.

   You can utilize inheritance if you like and it makes sense. However, be aware that due to the way modelbinding works, you will still need to use your concrete, derived classes as params, not some base class. The modelbinder will instantiate the class specified by the param (so it can't be abstract), bind any request values represented on *that* class, and discard the rest. So if you bind to `BaseClass`, all you will have is `BaseClass`, not `DerivedClass`, even if the request body was a representation of `DerivedClass`. If you then attempted to downcast to `DerivedClass`, all the properties specific to `DerivedClass` would be null/default.
2. It is neither good nor bad practice. JSON is an object representation format. If your object has nested objects, then your JSON would have nested JSON.

Comment: So for lets say a `Customer` entity, I should have a separate DTO for get and separate DTO for post? How does that makes sense and what value does having multiple DTOs add?

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul: Any time you have a different set of data, there should be a separate DTO to represent that particular set of data. Simple as that. If different methods utilize the same dataset, then they can share the same DTO. What you *don't* want to do and shouldn't do is use try to create some super DTO that includes a bunch of properties and then use that for multiple methods where only some subset of that data is employed in each. That's bad design.

Comment: In my case let say when i post customer. Customer dto has primary key which i generate before save changes to database. If i use same dto in put request and use automapper to map properties. It will give me sql error because primary can't be modified. However if i make seperate dto without customer id i simply map properties and save changes and it works.

Comment: I will post some code snippets when i get home it will be clear what i am trying to ask. And thanks guys for reply

Answer (score -2):

1. **Can we have separate DTO for GET, POST and PUT request?**

DTOs are not created based on the request type, instead DTOs are created for entities. For example you have a `Customer` entity, for the `Customer` entity you will create a `Customer` DTO and the same `Customer` DTO can be used for GET, POST and PUT requests of `Customer` entity.

**Can I make one abstract class with common properties and then inherit from it?**

Yes you can use inheritance while creating your DTOs but I would say thats over complication for no added value and keep in mind that inheritance, if not used properly can increase coupling in system.

2. **Is sending nested json in POST request a good practice?**

As Chris mentioned in his answer, if your object has a nested object then your JSON will have nested JSON.

Comment: you answer to the first question is not correct in my opinion. What if you customer looks differently in different lifecycle states. E.g. a customer that is not persisted yet and that is coming from the browser does not have an ID. Yet, a customer that is coming from the database and is being sent to the browser will always have an ID. You should create a different DTO for the 2 usecases